Setup Unity Catalog with Apache Spark in a docker container
I am trying to set up Unity Catalog in a docker container with Apache Spark 3.5.2, but I am running into errors.

I followed this document to set up and test Unity Catalog with Apache Spark.
As per the instructions there I need to start the spark shell with jars of delta-spark and unity-catalog.
I built the unity catalog jar from its github repo using
the command mentioned in the readme file.

build/sbt clean package publishLocal spark/publishLocal



But I am getting an error for both delta-spark and unity catalog:

For delta-spark it throws the error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/IterableOnce`

which looks like a Scala version conflict, but I tried multiple combinations like delta-spark_2.12:3.0.0 etc.

For Unity catalog it throws:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.unitycatalog.client.ApiException`



Can someone please review this, and help me get rid of these errors?
My goal is to be able to set up and use Unity Catalog with Apache Spark in a docker container.
Here is my GitHub branch and the steps to reproduce it are written in the pull request comments:
https://github.com/experientlabs/spark-dp-101/pull/1
Steps to reproduce:

Get this dev_branch in your machine: https://github.com/experientlabs/spark-dp-101/pull/1

Do a docker build, you can use the below command - Build(docker build command):
docker build -t spark-delta-unity-catalog .


Run the docker run command - Run(docker run command):
hostfolder="$(pwd)"
dockerfolder="/home/sparkuser/app"

docker run --rm -it --name spark-uc \
-p 4040:4040 -p 18080:18080 -p 8080:8080 \
spark-delta-unity-catalog:latest bashed


Once in the docker container bash shell, run the below commands to launch spark-shell - Spark Shell with Unity Catalog
/home/spark/bin/spark-shell --verbose \
--jars /home/spark/jars/unitycatalog-spark-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
--packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.13:3.2.0 \
--conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=io.unitycatalog.connectors.spark.UCSingleCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.uri=http://localhost:8080 \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.unity=io.unitycatalog.connectors.spark.UCSingleCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.unity.uri=http://localhost:8080


After you get the spark-shell try running any of the catalog queries:

sql("SET spark.sql.defaultCatalog").show(truncate=false), or
sql("SELECT current_catalog()").show(truncate=false)



I get io.unitycatalog.client.ApiException on trying to run any catalog query.

are you solve the problem?
how can add minio to the project?

Please note from version compatibility between Apache Spark™ and Unity Catalog that you will need:

Unity Catalog >= 0.2
Apache Spark >= 3.5.3
Delta Lake >= 3.2.1

per Unity Catalog Apache Spark™ Integration.
Could you please update to at least these versions? As of this writing, we're currently updating the UC docker as well to streamline this process.
